# passing properties to dojo widget and refresh

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I have an assignment and I'm stuck up in one section as I'm learning dojo widget.

At first, I have created the main widget that contains the layout(left, center, bottom panes).
In the left pane, I have attached the tree widget(employee names being listed in the tree).
In the center pane, I have attached a custom widget as per requirement(employee details).
same in the bottom pane a data grid, custom widget as per requirement(other employee details in a grid).

I have planned to write code so that I can click on child nodes of the tree widget of the left pane and pass the ID of the employee to the properties other two widgets(widgets on center and bottom pane) and see the corresponding employee details being displayed as per click.

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not able to pass values on the widgets as they are separate entities.

### Tree widget(at the left pane):

```
var tree = new dijit.Tree({model: tree_model, onClick: function(e){
console.log(e.id[0]); /*clicking on the tree nodes, i'm able to see the user id of the current selection*/
});
```

### Bottom Grid(Custome widget at the bottom pane):

```
var bottomGridWid = new custom.bottomGrid({default_user_id: userid});
//passing different userid to the widget will automatically query the grid and display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

All widgets are given an unique Id, if not provided at the time of creation.
In your case, it is best to provide a unique ID to the widget during its creation.
Use the ID for getting hold ( reference ) of the widget. Need to use the API dijit.registry.byId() to get a reference to the widget
Have a look at the below link
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html
After you get hold of the widget you can manipulate it using widgets specific API.